# ¿Como puedo conseguir los puntos decimales en java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Necesito mostrar al usuario un monto a pagar, pero el resultado devuelto es el siguiente **1700.292** el usuario le parecerá un error.

Se necesita mostrar el monto exacto separados por puntos -> 1.700.292

> Resultado Correcto: 1.700.292
>
> Resultado erroneo que es el que me da ahora: 1700.292

salarioMensual = 785.292

cestaTiket = 915.000

salarioMensual + cestaTiket;
= 1.700.292

```
public class Prueba{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   
   double value1 = 785.292;
   
   double value2 = 915.000;
   
   System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1 + value2));
 
   }

}
```

**¿Como puedos usar la clase para lograr tener los puntos decimales?**

Comment: no deberias usar `double` para expresar valores monetarios, considera usar `BigDecimal` si tu moneda usa decimales,`BigInteger` sino. Si escribes un numero como `785.292` no quiere decir `785 mil 292`, sino `785 unidades con 292 milesimas`.

Comment: Claro de considero esa clase, aún no se como implementarla para este caso. Si cuentas con un ejemplo o información no dudes en enviarla

Answer (score 4):

Creo que lo que buscas hacer seria de la siguiente forma.

```
public class Prueba{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");

    double value1 = 785.292;

    double value2 = 915.000;

    System.out.println(formateador.format(value1 + value2));

   }
}
```

**Recuerda importar la libreria de:**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

Comment: Buena funciona bien

Comment: Eso me agrada :D

Comment: Funciona perfecto!!

Comment: Hola Hector, si se te ha dado una respuesta correcta, estaría bien que la marcases como tal (pulsando sobre la v que hay bajo la puntuación de la pregunta) ya que le darás reputación al usuario que te ha contestado y ayudará a futuros usuarios que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: Ojo con el locale, podrias usar la version `new DecimalFormat(String, Locale)` para especificar el locale correcto.

Comment: @Klaimmore como hago eso? Porque necesito especificar un valor de este tipo por mi región... 1.764.234,34

Answer (score 1):

Puedes darle formato a tu numero. Mira este ejemplo:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double value1 = 785.292;
    double value2 = 915.000;
    double value=value1+value2;
    java.text.NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
    String valString = nf.format(value).replace(".",".");
    System.out.println(valString);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considera usar el locale para un formato correcto, dependiendo de la region:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("es");

    format(12345678.9, new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale)));
    format(12345678.9, NumberFormat.getInstance(locale));
}

private static void format(double n, NumberFormat format) {
    System.out.print(n);
    System.out.print(" => ");
    System.out.println(format.format(n));
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, voy a probar amigo!!